# Shelf life prediction using polynomial fit of several results

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression, non-linear-regression

I have results of several batches of the same product over time, e.g.:

```
x1 = np.array([0, 3, 6]) # x coordinates of batch1
y1 = np.array([0.51, 0.69, 0.78]) # y coordinates of batch1
batch1 = '29880G001'
x2 = np.array([0, 3, 6]) # x coordinates of batch2
y2 = np.array([0.29, 0.77, 0.61]) # y coordinates of batch2
batch2 = '30565G002'
x3 = np.array([0, 3, 6]) # x coordinates of batch3
y3 = np.array([0.29, 0.61, 0.6]) # y coordinates of batch3
batch3 = '30657G003'
```

Y values are time in months and X values are a lab result for the specific batch.
Presenting them on a chart:
[image: An example chart]

I am looking for a way to make ONE polynominal fit to these results which I can carry forward, i.e. extrapolate, to make predictions on the product behaviour in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat your arrays and do [`polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html):

```
np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(np.r_[x1,x2,x3], np.r_[y1,y2,y3], 3)
```

**But I very much doubt that it makes much sense to use a polynomial to extrapolate.**

Example:

```
z = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(np.r_[x1,x2,x3], np.r_[y1,y2,y3], 3)

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'bo', x2, y2, 'ro', x3, y3, 'go')
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, z))
```

[image]

Comment: Would you suggest a different method?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no simple method for predicting the future. I mean when you have data for x = 0 to 6 and they follow a regular pattern you could extrapolate say to 7, but the farer you extrapolate the less sensible the results will get (especially for higher degree polynomials). Maybe you should look into [time series analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).

Comment: Can't you limit the change at the "unkown" i.e. future range?

Comment: you can play around with the degree, e.g. use 1 for a linear trend or 2 for a quadratic, but I guess you'd need far more data to get meaningful results.